# Ansible fails to find boto3 and botocore although installed

Tags: python, amazon-s3, ansible, ansible-2.x

The following task:

```
  - name: Fetch dump file from S3
      aws_s3:
        bucket: mybucket
        object: somedump.sql
        dest: /tmp/somedump.sql
        mode: get
      delegate_to: "{{ ec2_instance_ip }}"
```

fails with:

> fatal: [localhost -> 22.33.111.88]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "boto3 and botocore required for this module"}

```
$ ssh ubuntu@22.33.111.88
$ pip freeze
boto3==1.7.41
botocore==1.10.41

$ pip3 freeze
blinker==1.3
boto3==1.7.41
botocore==1.10.41
```

The target machine is `ubuntu/xenial` so I have also taken care of installing `python-minimal` (given that out of the box the machine only had `python3`)

Therefore, on the target machine:

```
$(which python) --version
Python 2.7.12
```

I have run the above play with and without appending:

```
  vars:
    ansible_python_interpreter: /usr/bin/python3
```

at the end of the task...

Comment: Nothing in your question indicates that Ansible runs the same Python executable as `pip` does.

Comment: Ι have run the task with and without (i.e. with the default used by ansible: `/usr/bin/python`) setting the interpeter to `/usr/bin/python3`; what other Python executable is left to try to run the task with?

Comment: I don't know. You should, you are sitting at the console. You execute some `pip` and you seem to think it should run the same Python as Ansible's default. Prove that it does.

Comment: no I didn't think that; I exhausted all the python2/python3 combinations; i.e. pip3 (lists both boto3/botocore as installed) should run python3 and therefore tried the task with python3; pip (lists both boto3/botocore as installed) should run python2 and therefore tried the task with python(2); there is no other python executable on the system left to try and run the task with **either way**;

Comment: no because I am not trying to prove sth; I am countering the argument that the issue is due to a wrong python executable or a misalignment between the python executables used by pip and ansible (as you hinted); to put it simply the task fails __no matter the python executable used__

Comment: I met with this problem, too. turns out to be permission issue, after adding become:yes to the task, it went well.

Comment: @Wen What permissions you added?

Answer (score 4):

Could you try to downgrade "boto3" package to see if there is no issue there?

Get available versions:

```
pip install boto3==some_nonsense_word
```

Then:

```
pip uninstall boto3
```

Finally:

```
pip install boto3==<VERSION>
```

---

Answer based on the findings from the following GitHub issue comment:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-modules-core/issues/2014#issuecomment-144620598

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on MacOS and downgrading didn't fix the issue. However, adding the following python path to a `hosts` file fixed the issue:

```
[local]
localhost              ansible_connection=local     ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Afterwards, you can run your ansible playbook with the hosts as:

```
ansible-playbook -i ./hosts playbook.yml
```

---

Or you set the path to python in the execution:

```
ansible-playbook -i localhost, playbook.yml --extra-vars "ansible_python_interpreter=/Users/admin/temp/ansec2/venv/bin/python"
```

---

If you're on Mac and you have installed other copies of python via homebrew, you can run these commands to install boto to the system python:

```
sudo /usr/bin/python -m easy_install pip
sudo /usr/bin/python -m pip install boto
```

---

Here are more solutions to the issue:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/15019